# How to perform offline testing for apps that depend on JSON?

Tags: java, android, ios, json, swift

Frequently, I write small apps that rely on a web service that provides JSON at various points (login, configuration, request info, etc). For UI development/testing, I usually just keep a few dummy JSON files in the app bundle that can be read locally. Is this the most common practice, and are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: You can load the json from file or make one "fake server" in Node

Comment: I use dummy json files too and its the commom and easy to use

Comment: why do you want to change, as its a good aproach

Comment: [Helpful](https://github.com/lemberg/android-json-serializable-sample/wiki/Unit-Tests)

Answer (score 1):

Well,

If by "offline" you mean you absoluteky can't have any internet access, I guess you don't have any choice. Although, this will mean that you will not be able to test your web services calls.

Otherwise, if you are using API calls, you can use free API servers such as http://myjson.com/api. These are simple JSON store for your web or mobile app.

I often use it during development phase.

Hope it may help.